# Add code to WordPress header, which appears for only one language version

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a WordPress site translated with WPML in many languages, including: EN, DE, IT, CH, etc.

I want to add some code to the template header but I want this code to appear only to one site version, for example EN.

The problem is that the same homepage template file is used on all other languages.

Is there a way to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditions:

```
if ( 'en' == ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE ) {
    // only if language is english
}
```

Or if you wish to use text directly in your templates, and this text should translated in the current language, you can use [i18n](https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers).

```
<?php echo __('This text is english', 'your-text-domain'); ?>
```

You can translate this strings easely with [WPML String Translation](https://wpml.org/download/wpml-string-translation/) in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='en') {
add your code here for english version
 }
```

'en' is the code for english like wise you can have different codes for different languages as per WPML